# Issue with Capslock key on Laptop

Tags: keyboard, windows-vista

For some reason my laptop has a mind of its own and the Caps Lock tends to come on whenever it feels like it. I thought it was an software issue from that reasoning, but I later cleared the OS and then reinstalled it hoping to fix the problem, but it didn't. Not only does it do that it also comes on and off whenever the letters A, S, and left shift key are pushed.

So I assummed it was a keyboard issue and that the keyboard needs to be replaced, but it has one of those touch pad cap lock buttons also, because even when I press that button it tends to not react. So how can that be fixed with a keyboard replacement or is that connected still?

**EDIT** - I followed the direction with the following code in  notepad and it didn't do the job:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
“Scancode Map”=hex:00000000 00000000 0200000000 00003A00 00000000
```

Comment: A laptop model number and maybe some pictures would help this question greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caliban your approach worked pefectly, but the link you gave me solution wasnt disabling it for me, but This solution from vistax64.com worked, it was a little different but did the job: [Disable the Caps Lock Key](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/172191-caps-lock-key-enable-disable.html)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if the CAPSLOCK key is entirely useless to you, instead of spending hard-earned money trying to repair the notebook, why not just disable the CAPS key entirely? :)

Check [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/) out for how to do so...

**EDIT** For some reasons (it worked when I tested it), the registry codes at the top does not seem to work for people. Recommending another solution - this time an application.

[CAPS UnLock](http://www.brainsystems.com/capsunlock/) - Allows systems to disable Caps Lock and Insert keys.

Comment: This looks like a GREAT idea for my fat fingers.

Will it work on XP and where is it?

Comment: @Xavierjazz : Mate, here ya go. :) http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/04/how-to-disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-xp-and-vista/

Comment: although this solution might work, which I will try when I get to my computer, I still would like to know what kind of issue was it in case I ever decided to fix it the right way

Comment: tried it and it didnt disable..i already restarted it

Comment: I found it didn't disable either. It simply beeps when you hit the CAPS LOCK key

Comment: edited answer - gave you all an app instead of some registry mumbo jumbo.

Comment: @caliban I edited your answer because there was `http://superuser.com/questions` in your edit, right in the middle of a word. Oh, and +1 for the answer.